# Is the function continuous that maps a vector to the coefficients of its expansion in a basis?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, continuity

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space with basis $e_1, e_2, \ldots, e_n$.

Consider the function $f:V\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ defined such that, for each $v\in V$, $f(v)=(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$ where $v = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i e_i$. Since $e_i$ form a basis we are assured the map is well-defined and injective.

Is $f$ continuous?

Comment: well what is the topology on $V$?,norm?, or metric?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function $f$ is a linear operator (check this!) between finite dimensional spaces. Assuming your topology on $V$ is induced by some norm, all such operators are continuous. In order to show this, you might like to introduce some norm $\|\cdot\|$ on $V$ then show that there exists $C\in\mathbb{R}$ such that, for any $v\in V$,
$$|f(v)|\leq C\|v\|.$$
Since $f$ is linear, this would imply $f$ is Lipschitz (again, you should check this) and hence continuous. The above inequality is a finite-dimensional example of one of the fundamental facts of functional analysis: an operator between normed vector spaces is continuous if and only if it is bounded.

Note that given how little information about $V$ we have, the most sensible norm to choose would be of the form
$$\|a_1v_1+\ldots+a_nv_n\|:=\|(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\|_{\mathbb{R}^n}$$
where $\|\cdot\|_{\mathbb{R}^n}$ is a norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$. However by construction this would make your function an isometry, which is obviously continuous.

Comment: Gah yes of course. Thank you!

Comment: Follow-up which in retrospect was what I was really asking: are each of its component functions continuous? The space is R^n and the norm is L2. I'll edit the question to reflect this
Edit: 
AH nevermind it is a projection so continouous

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if this is all already clear, but the question starts with a finite-dimensional normed vector space $V$, and, by picking a basis $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$, defines a linear isomorphism $f\colon V\to \mathbb R^n$, where $f(v) = (a_1,\ldots,a_n)^t$ if $v = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i v_i$.

The question is then whether the linear map $f$ is continuous. The answer is "yes", and the reason this is automatic is because the spaces are finite-dimensional: any linear map $\alpha\colon X\to Y$ between normed vector spaces is automatically continuous if $\dim(X)<\infty$. It is not too hard to reduce this to the following:

***Claim***: any linear map $\gamma\colon (\mathbb R^n, \|.\|_1)\to (X,\|.\|)$ from $\mathbb R^n$ equipped with the $\ell_1$-norm (*i.e.*, $\|x\|_1 = \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|$) and an arbitrary normed vector space $(X,\|.\|)$ is automatically continuous, and moreover if it is invertible, its inverse, $\gamma^{-1}$ is also continuous.

The fact that $\gamma$ is bounded is straight-forward: Let $\{e_i: 1\leq i\leq n\}$ denote the standard basis of $\mathbb R^n$. Then if $v =(c_1,\ldots,c_n)^t$ we have
$$
\|\gamma(\sum_{i=1}^n c_ie_i)\|\leq \sum_{i=1}^n |c_i|\|\gamma(e_i)\|,
$$
so that if $M = \mathrm{max}\{\|\gamma(e_i)\|: 1\leq i\leq n\}$, then $\|\gamma(v)\|\leq M.\|v\|_1$, and $\alpha$ is bounded (and thus continuous) as required.

For the final part, the key is the fact that $S^{n-1} = \{x\in \mathbb R^n: \|x\|_1 = 1\}$ is closed and bounded, and hence by Bolzano-Weierstrass compact. Indeed $\gamma^{-1}$ is continuous if and only if it is bounded, that is, there is some $C>0$ with $\|\gamma^{-1}(v)\|_1\leq C\|v\|$ for all $v \in V$, or (taking $v=\gamma(x)$) $C^{-1}\|x\|_1 \leq \|\gamma(x)\|$ for all $x\in \mathbb R^n$. But this holds trivially if $x=0$, and for $x \neq 0$ we have
$$
\begin{split}
C^{-1}\|x\|_1 \leq \|\gamma(x)\|, \forall x \in \mathbb R^n\backslash \{0\} &\iff C^{-1} \leq \|\gamma(\frac{x}{\|x\|_1})\|, \forall x \in \mathbb R^n\backslash \{0\} \\
&\iff C^{-1}\leq \|\gamma(x)\|, \forall x \in S^{n-1}
\end{split}
$$

But as $\gamma$ is continuous the map $x \mapsto \|\gamma(x)\|$ is a continuous real-valued function on $ S^{n-1}$, thus since $S^{n-1}$ is compact, $\|\gamma(x)\|$ attains its extrema, so that there is an $x_0 \in S^{n-1}$ with $\|\gamma(x_0)\|\leq \|\gamma(x)\|$ for all $x \in S^{n-1}$. But $\gamma$ is an isomorphism, so $\gamma(x_0)\neq 0$ and hence $C^{-1} = \|\gamma(x_0)\|>0$, and thus $\gamma^{-1}$ is bounded as claimed.

To deduce the main assertion from the claim, suppose $\alpha\colon X\to Y$ is a linear map and $\dim(X)=n<\infty$. Then picking a basis $\{b_1,\ldots,b_n\}$ of $X$ we may define a linear isomorphism $\gamma\colon \mathbb R^n\to X$ by $\gamma((x_1,\ldots,x_n)^t) = \sum_{i=1}^n x_ib_i$. By the claim, both $\gamma$ and $\gamma^{-1}$ are continuous, and, again by the claim, $\alpha\circ \gamma\colon \mathbb R^n \to Y$ is continuous. But then $\alpha = (\alpha\circ \gamma)\circ (\gamma^{-1})$ is a composition of continuous functions and hence is itself continuous. (Where we view $\mathbb R^n$ as a normed vector space using the $\|.\|_1$-norm.)